# How to serve angular cli app before running cypress in CI?

Tags: angular, cypress

I am trying to use Cypress with an Angular (v. 5) CLI application.

The tests works fine when running locally, because here I can just start the serve command before running the cypress tests.

I tried following the documentation [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Command-Line),
but none of the commands seems to be working.

I tried varioues combination, looking like this:

```
"cypress:run:report": "./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --record --key <key>",
"cypress:run:ci": "start-server-and-test serve:dev http://localhost:4200 cypress:run:report",
"cypress:run:ci2": "npm run -s serve:dev & npm run -s cypress:run:report",
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey! Do you mind changing the correct answer to the most upvoted answer? That may save some folks :D

Comment: Consider it done @Dev 

Comment: Thanks buddy :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Latest Cypress updates already include Angular schematics to simplify tests integration into an existing project.

As simple as: `ng add @cypress/schematic`

and then `ng e2e`

Comment: Thanks for the trick, i didn't know that yet. However, this command doesn't seem to work in the pipeline, since it's not running in headless mode. Is there maybe any flag which makes that work?

Comment: Ok, I found it out myself. I just need to run `ng run ${project-name}:cypress-run` :)

Comment: Best option. Very reliable and supported

Answer (score 17):

I wasn't satisfied with any of the answers provided, so I came up with the following:

**Step 1**: Install dev dependencies

```
npm install --save-dev concurrently wait-on
```

**Step 2**: Write the following scripts in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "ng serve",
  ...
  "cy:open": "cypress open",
  "cy:run": "cypress run",
  "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run start\" \"wait-on http-get://localhost:4200 && npm run cy:run\" --kill-others --success first",
  "e2e-gui": "concurrently \"npm run start\" \"wait-on http-get://localhost:4200 && npm run cy:open\" --kill-others --success first",
  ...
}
```

Then you can run `npm run e2e` or `npm run e2e-gui`.

Voila!

Answer (score 5):

start-server-and-test does not seem to integrate well with the 'ng serve' command. 
I got it to work by not using angular-cli for serving the app - no Modules API required:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "ci:serve": "ng build && http-server dist -p 4200",
    "cy:run": "cypress run",
    "cy:ci": "start-server-and-test ci:serve http://localhost:4200 cy:run"
}
"devDependencies": {
    // omitted angular & cypress deps
    "start-server-and-test": "x.x.x",
    "http-server": "x.x.x"
}
```

Comment: You can actually get it to work with ng serve if you put the ng serve in a separate start script and then change the cy:ci script to: start-server-and-test start http-get://localhost:4200 cy:run

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that start-server-and-test is an NPM package that needs to be installed

Answer (score 5):

**Step 1:** Install devDependencies:

```
npm i -D angular-http-server start-server-and-test
```

[angular-http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-http-server) to create a simple dev-server

[start-server-and-test](https://www.npmjs.com/package/start-server-and-test) to starts server, waits for URL, then runs test command; when the tests end, shuts down server

**Step 2:** Add scripts on *package.json*

```js
"scripts": {
  "build": "ng build",
  "cy:run": "cypress run",
  "ci:cy-run": "start-server-and-test ci:start-server 4200 cy:run",
  "ci:start-server": "angular-http-server --silent --path ./dist/project-name -p 4200"
}
```

**Step 4:** Add this commands to your CI scripts:

```js
npm run build
npm run ci:cy-run
```

**Optional**: Consider turning off videos and screenshotOnRunFailure on `cypress.json` and `support` directory

Answer (score 2):

After trying to solve this for some hours, I developed a solution using the [Cypress Module API](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#Cypress-Module-API).

**Package.json**

```
"cypress:run:ci": "node ng-serve-and-run-cypress.js",
```

**ng-serve-and-run-cypress**

```
'use strict';

const cypress = require('cypress');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const child = spawn('ng', ['serve']);

// On error exit, and print
child.on('error', (err) => process.exit(1));
child.stderr.on('data', (data) => console.log(data.toString()));
// On exit, print exit code
child.on('exit', (code, signal) => console.log(`Child exitting with code ${code}`));

child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    const asString = data.toString();
    // Log the output to inform CI/User
    console.log(asString);
    if (asString.includes('webpack: Compiled successfully.')) {
        cypress.run({})
        .then((results) => {
            const errorCode = (results.failures >= 1) ? 1 : 0;
            child.kill();
            // When cypress is done running the tests, exit with errorCode from above.
            process.exit(errorCode);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            child.kill();
            // If cypress hit's an error, exit with code 1
            process.exit(1);
        })
    }
});
```

Just post here if you are interested in more details.

Comment: There's an NPM library called start-server-and-test that does something similar to this script. It's mentioned in Bastian Stein's answer. Commenting here because that wasn't immediately obvious to me

Answer (score 1):

After trying several solution found on the Web I adopted the following one that is pretty nice and straightforward:

First of all you need to install `wait-on` and `npm-run-all` libs.

```
npm i wait-on npm-run-all --save-dev
```

`wait-on` waits the app to be served (up and running) on a specific port before proceeding with the next command
`npm-run-all` allows to run multiple commands in parallel.

Here as it should appear the scripts section:

```
"scripts": {
   ...
   "serve": "ng serve",
   "cy:wait-run": "./node_modules/.bin/wait-on http-get://localhost:4200/ && cypress run",
   "cy:serve-and-run": "node_modules/.bin/run-p -r \"serve\" \"cy:wait-run\" "
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used lite-server because http-server didnt work out of the box for me with Angular routing.

```
npm i -D  lite-server && start-server-and-test
```

then in my package.json file

```
"scripts": {
   "ci:serve:employee-onboarding": "ng build --prod --project=employee-onboarding && lite-server -c lite-server-employee-onboarding-config.json",
   "cypress:ci:employee-onboarding": "start-server-and-test ci:serve:employee-onboarding http://localhost:4201 cy:run:employee-onboarding",
   "cy:run:employee-onboarding": "node_modules/.bin/cypress run --config-file ./apps/employee-onboarding-e2e/cypress-ci.json",
}
```

I run it like this:

```
npm run cypress:ci:employee-onboarding
```

my cypress-ci.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:4201/",
  "integrationFolder": "apps/employee-onboarding-e2e/cypress/integration/employee-onboarding/tests-with-server-calls-mocked/",
  "fixturesFolder": "apps/employee-onboarding-e2e/cypress/fixtures"
}
```

and my lite-server-employee-onboarding-config.json file looks like this:

```
{
   "port": 4201,
   "server": { "baseDir": "dist/apps/employee-onboarding" }
}
```